# How do I import magento categories programmatically with categories having a specified category_id

Tags: magento-1.8, category, importexport

I have a need to import magento categories with the following fields.

Note. I want to import even the category Ids coz I need them as they are. Do want to have new ones on import.

[image]

How do I do this using a script?

Or it there any extension that can handle this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the csv file where you add into folder directory

```
$uri = "myfile.csv";
```

The below code used to read the csv file content where $uri is the path of you csv file.
$count is used to get teh file data for initials to last element block.

```
$mydata = array();
            if (($handle = fopen($uri, "r")) !== FALSE) 
            {
                $count=0;
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
                    {
                       if($count!=0)
                       {
                            $mydata['id'][] =$data[0]; // id of category array
                            $mydata['name'][] =$data[1];// name array
                           // and add array as you like field in csv file.
                       }
                        $count++;
                    }
            }
```

the output of above code will make a array of 'id' and 'name' associated with the array unique key.

```
foreach($mydata['id'] as $key=>$catdata)
                {
echo $name = $mydata['name'][$key];
//you can get the name of category associate with the key field

// to add the category in magento here you go 


$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
                                                  $category->setStoreId(0); 
                                                  $categoryName =  $name;
                                                  $rootCategory['name'] = $categoryName;
                                                  $rootCategory['path'] = "1/2"; 
                                                  //$rootCategory['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS";
                                                  $rootCategory['is_active'] = 1;

                                                  $category->addData($rootCategory);
                                                  try 
                                                  {
                                                    $category->save();
                                                    $CategoryId = $category->getId();
                                                  }
                                                  catch (Exception $e)
                                                  {
                                                    echo "categories not found";
                                                  }


}
```

I hope this post will help you : thankyou

Comment: this did not work